# How to EASILY add a map legend to a map in Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, legend

I'm new to Geoserver and Neatline and somewhat to HTML coding! But, I am clueless as how to 'EASILY & Cheaply " include a simple legend on a map using a WMS statement. I have been able to use singularly the WMS "get legend request to get a simple legend, Is it possible to combined the "get legend" request with the "get map" WMS request into one WMS statement which I could imbed into a Neatline exhibit and publish the map with a legend!

Is this possible? Or if not what is the easiest way?

Thanks

Robert Jackson

Answer (score 3):

You can add a legend to the results of GetMap using a:

1) GeoServer has the ability to overlay decorations onto your map.

- http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/advanced/wmsdecoration.html

2) Adding a legend is also something done by the print module.

- http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/printing/